# Is there a workaround to enable genymotion plugin in Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

After installing the fresh Android Studio 3.0 stable, I encountered that Genymotion plugin doesn't work properly (the icon doesn't appear). To use genymotion I have to manually start Genymotion from my OS. Did someone resolved this issue?

P.S. I understand that the Genymotion team maybe didn't solve yet this issue for Android Studio 3.0, but maybe is there an workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me and several other colleagues, did you follow the doc: https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/

especially "To see Genymotion plugin icon, display the toolbar by clicking View > Toolbar."